# How much work am I doing here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, friction

If I pull a block horizontally with a rope, I am pulling with a force of $20$ N and there is $10$ N of friction resisting the motion.

I want to calculate the work done: $$W=Fd$$

Is $F$ my total force $20$ N, or the resultant force $10$ N ?

I'm thinking the resultant, but I have seen the total used in a textbook and I'm questioning myself now.

Let's take d = 1 metre for simplicity.

Comment: YOU are doing 20d joules of work. However there are 10d joules of work on the block

Comment: @jensenpaull How are you getting work from the info given? I see no distance given.

Comment: @jensenpaull He assumed 1 m I guess. I've included a value of d=1 for others.

Comment: I assigned the variable d for distance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The work *you do* on the block is based on the force you apply to it, 20 N, times the distance traveled by the block. The *net work* done on the block, which equals the work you do minus the work done by friction, is based on the net force applied to the block, 10 N, times the distance traveled by the block. The net work done on the block will equal its change in kinetic energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "The net work done on the block will equal its change in kinetic energy." surely the block stops as soon as the force stops pulling, as the kinetic energy is quickly dissipated by friction. I'm not sure what you consider "its change in kinetic energy" in this context?

Comment: @njzk2 If the force stops pulling the net force changes and becomes only the friction force. The change in KE is the KE the object had before the pulling force stops minus the final KE which is zero since the friction force will bring it to a stop. But WHILE the pulling force is present AND  friction is present there the net force is 10 N. If the object moves 1 meter then the KE at the end of the meter minus the KE at the start of the meter will equal the net work done, i.e., 10 J.

Comment: @njzk2 correct and this is one of the biggest sources of confusion for students new to the work energy theorem. The point is that as long as there is $10$ J of net force, you are "over-pulling." You are pulling harder than you need to and thus accelerating the block, which will result in it having gained some kinetic energy by the time you let go. After you let go all of the force on the block is due to friction and opposes the direction of motion, i.e. friction does work on the block to bring it to rest.

Comment: This is unintuitive because we seldom "over-pull" in real life manual labor situations. Why don't we? Because intuitively we know that all of the force we apply in excess of the friction does work that will only be dissipated by friction the second we stop applying the excessive force. If we pull with less force than friction, the block stays put. If we over-pull, we just waste our energy. We intuitively pull to exactly oppose the force of friction, which means that situations with a net force are very unintuitive for us -- we simply don't experience them often.